# Is $GL(\mathbb R)$ a non-commutatif field?

Tags: field-theory

Is $GL(\mathbb R)$ a non-commutatif field ? Since $GL(\mathbb R)$ is a ring an that all element are invertible, I would says that it's a field, but since elements doesn't commute for $\cdot $, I would says that it's not commutatif. Therefore it's a non commutatif field. The problem it's it's precise no-where and the only example of non-commutatif field are the quaternion, so maybe $GL(\mathbb R)$ is not a field...

Comment: What does $GL(\mathbb{R})$ mean?  The invertible linear transformations on $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over itself?

Comment: In what way is $GL(\mathbb R)$ a ring? (and, for that matter, what is it?)

Comment: @EricWofsey: Yes. **Mariano :** $GL(\mathbb R)$ is a subring of the ring of the matrix, isn't it ?

Comment: @Rick, well, no.

Answer (score 3):

It's not even a ring (at least in any obvious way) because it isn't closed under addition.  It also is commutative, because it can be identified with the set of nonzero real numbers (every $\mathbb{R}$-linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself is just multiplication by some scalar).